# y-axis length for LOWESS curve in Stata

Tags: regression, data-visualization, stata, loess

I have a problem considering the length of the *y*-axis in a LOWESS plot in Stata. The *y* variable ranges from 0 to 50. I would like to run the LOWESS on all the data but only display the graph for the range of *y* from 30 to 50. I've searched throughout the net, but I just found that I would also have to restrict the data to $\ge$ 30, but that of course changes the curve. 
Do you have any advice? The graphs are simply unusable for that *y*-axis interval.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you have in mind?

```
sysuse auto
lowess price mpg, gen(yhat)
tw (line yhat mpg if price <12000, sort) (scatter yhat mpg if price <12000)
```

In practice, this seems like a curious thing to do.

Comment: Dimitriy, you are restricting the x-axis. The OP wants to constain the y-axis, probably because their data are wildly skewed, and nothing is seen on the full scale. So rather than `if mpg<20`, the OP probably wants to entertain `if price < 10000`... although `auto.dta` price isn't badly enough skewed for this to make much sense :)

Comment: @StasK If only reading was as easy as using Stata. Excellent point, and fixed.